# centering does not center text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to simply center the text in latex in simple article.

The following code does not center the text - the full width can be seen on print screen and is higlighted

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge 
Surname1
\newline 
Name1
\newline
\normalsize 
Institution
\end{center} 

\centering
\Huge 
Surname1
\newline 
Name1
\newline
\normalsize 
Institution


\end{document}
```

This is so simple that there can't be a place for a mistake.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: you probably want `\documentclass[a4paper][article}` if you have specified A4 as your default paper size when installing texlive

Comment: What if I would like to specify a6paper?

Comment: easiest is to use geometry package to specify page size

Comment: I had a code with geometry package included with the same issue : P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\\` in the scope of `center`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge 
Surname1
\\
Name1
\\
\normalsize 
Institution
\end{center} 

\centering
\Huge 
Surname1
\\
Name1
\\
\normalsize 
Institution

X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\newline` is designed to leave lines short in justified text so it adds glue to one side of the line, that throws the text off centre. Normally you do not need either, just leave a blank line in the source., note also that `\normalsize` does not start a new paragraph which was why the text was touching as you were setting Huge text on a normal baseline

Comment: Wow, that works. But why?

Comment: @MarcinKosiński `\newline` is designed to leave lines short in justified text so it adds glue to one side of the line, that throws the text off centre. Normally you do not need either, just leave a blank line in the source., note also that `\normalsize` does not start a new paragraph which was why the text was touching as you were setting Huge text on a normal baseline

Comment: shouldn't the `\\ ` come immediately after the text on that line?  or is it defined beginning with `\unskip`?  (spaces are ignored at the beginning of a line, but not at the end.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton usually it's better but actually in center it makes no difference as `\\` is more or less just `\par` really in this context:-)

Answer (score 3):

`\centering` redefines `\\`, but not `\newline`. Thus, `\newline` uses the setup for left aligned text (an additional `\hfil` on the right side of the previous line, ...). Using `\\` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge
Surname1
\\
Name1
\\
\normalsize
Institution
\end{center}

\centering
\Huge
Surname1
\\
Name1
\\
\normalsize
Institution

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]